# How to partial match with a string?

Tags: java

How can I type partial letters of a word to find this word?

For example:
I have a string array

```
 String[] s = {"Cartoon", "Cheese", "Truck", "Pizza"};
```

if I input partial letters, such as "ca","Che" or "piz"

then I can find the whole words for the list.

Thanks

Comment: Java's `String` has the `contains` function. Did you search the internet before asking a question? It's pretty basic stuff. Edit: oh yeah, as barbakini said in his answer, if you want the search to be case-insensitive you have to make the search term and the words all uppercase or lowercase and then use `contains`.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringValue.contains("string that you wanna search");
```

`.contains` will do the job, iterate over the loop and keep adding the words in `ArrayList<String>` for the matched ones.

This could be a good [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on string in java.

`.contains` is like `'%word%'` in mysql. There are other functions like `.startsWith` and `.endsWith` in java. You may use whatever suits the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
String userInput = (new Scanner(System.in)).next();
for (String string : s) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(userInput.toLowerCase()) return string;
}
```

Note that this is only going to return the first string in your list that contains whatever the user gave you so it's fairly imprecise.

Comment: you need to do `userInput.toLowerCase()` too for a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Thanks, included that now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [String#startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Apples");
list.add("Apples1214");
list.add("NotApples");
list.stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
             .filter(x->x.startsWith("app"))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you just want the `String` to be contained, then use [String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 0):

First cast all your strings upper or lower case and then use startsWith () method.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant

```
String[] s = {"Cartoon", "Cheese", "Truck", "Pizza"};
```

The easiest option would be to iterate through your string array and do a .contains on each individual String.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
   if(s[i].contains("car")){
      //do something like add to another list.
   }
 }
```

This ofcourse does not take caps into concideration. But this can easily be circumvented with .toLowerCare or .toUpperCase.